# Share wlan connection to ethernet using command line

Tags: ethernet, bridge, wlan, ifconfig

I have a wlan1 connection that I want to share to other computers on my LAN (via Ethernet - eth0). As this is somehow a temporary solution, I want this to be done *by a script*, so that I do not touch the network configuration files of my host (i.e I'll run this script after each reboot if I want to).

The problem is that **I am unable to bridge wlan1 and eth0**.

```
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0 wlan1
```

I saw that one needs to [enable 4addr](https://serverfault.com/questions/152363/bridging-wlan0-to-eth0):

```
 iw dev wlan1 set 4addr on
```

Indeed, I can then add wlan1 to the bridge, but ... I lose the wifi connection! I saw this is also a [common issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155041/bridging-loosing-wlan-network-connection-with-4addr-on-option-why) :(
In [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155041/bridging-loosing-wlan-network-connection-with-4addr-on-option-why), the solution says to do this

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add wds.wlan0 type managed 4addr on
ip link set dev wds.wlan0 addr $ADDR
ip link set dev wds.wlan0 up
```

where $ADDR is "WDS device address configured in the router". I don't understand what that is? The MAC address of my network card for wlan1?
And how should I then create my bridge? The following is not working:

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0 wds.wlan0
```

Or [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC), they suggest to install `ebtables`. But the page does not explain how I should create the bridge, and they modify `/etc/network/interfaces` which I do not want to do...

So, **can somebody please help me create that bridge correctly?**

So far, my wifi script is:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # this is for wlan1 - wifi connection
 pkill dhclient
 pkill wpa_supplicant
 ip link set dev wlan1 down
 ip addr flush dev wlan1
 iwconfig wlan1 essid "mywifi"
 iwconfig wlan1 frag 2432
 iwconfig wlan1 rts 2432
 ip link set dev wlan1 up   
 iwconfig wlan1 rate 1M
 dhclient -v wlan1

 # this is my IP address on my LAN
 ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.8 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I am running a Linux Mint 17.1 host. I have installed `bridge-utils`.

Comment: You generally can't bridge wireless adapters in Linux.  Why not simply use ip forwarding?

Comment: The thing is after creating the bridge eth0 and wlan1 will not have ips anymore, and it will be br0 that will got the common IP. It seems rather obvious the connection falls. If you want different IPs you have to use different IPs, and do NAT. Which I think it is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to bypass the bridging part and use `iptables` instead?

If so, you can setup source NAT to masquerade traffic going out on the wlan interface.

First you need to enable IP forwarding:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Next, you need to masquerade traffic going out:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Have the LAN connected hosts to use 192.168.0.8 as their default gateway and have your machine to use the wlan0 interface connected gateway as the default gateway.